# SQL query trim a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

I am using the following query to populate some data. From column "query expression" is there a way to remove any text that is to the left of N'Domain\

Basically I only want to see the text after N'Domain\ in the column "Query Expression" Not sure how to do this.

```
SELECT
  v_DeploymentSummary.SoftwareName,
  v_DeploymentSummary.CollectionName,
  v_CollectionRuleQuery.QueryExpression
FROM
v_DeploymentSummary
INNER JOIN v_CollectionRuleQuery
ON v_DeploymentSummary.CollectionID = v_CollectionRuleQuery.CollectionID
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Could you post sample data?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it.  For sql server, a combination of patindex() and right() should get the job done.

Comment: does every QueryExpression contain N'Domain\ ? Is N'Domain\ always the first 9 characters of the text ? This would make this question very easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for SQL Server:

```
SUBSTRING([v_CollectionRuleQuery.QueryExpression], CHARINDEX('N''Domain\', [v_CollectionRuleQuery.QueryExpression]) + 9, LEN([v_CollectionRuleQuery.QueryExpression])
```

Give it a try.

I didn't understand if you wanted to include N'Domain\ in your string if that's the case just remove the +9.

In my understanding you want something like this:

```
SELECT
  v_DeploymentSummary.SoftwareName,
  v_DeploymentSummary.CollectionName,
  SUBSTRING([v_CollectionRuleQuery.QueryExpression], CHARINDEX('N''Domain\', [v_CollectionRuleQuery.QueryExpression]) + 9, LEN([v_CollectionRuleQuery.QueryExpression])
FROM
v_DeploymentSummary
INNER JOIN v_CollectionRuleQuery
ON v_DeploymentSummary.CollectionID = v_CollectionRuleQuery.CollectionID
```

Comment: Thank you, where would I put this in my query at the end?

Comment: I edited the answer for showing you the final query in my understanding, if you are expecting to include the N'domain\ in your final query just remove the +9 which is an offset for substring to not include that.

Comment: Thank you, I had to remove the [ ] from the substring to work but now it says I have a syntax error on "FROM"?

Comment: Yes that's a good catch t-clausen, sine I don't know the data pretty much I went the simpler as possible.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can use `stuff()` for this purpose:

```
SELECT ds.SoftwareName, ds.CollectionName,
       STUFF(crq.QueryExpression, 1,
             CHARINDEX('Domain\', rq.QueryExpression) + LEN('Domain\') - 1,
             '')
FROM v_DeploymentSummary ds INNER JOIN
     v_CollectionRuleQuery crq
     ON ds.CollectionID = crq.CollectionID;
```

Note the use of table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: seems you are removing an extra character

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It will not change values for QueryExpression without the text N'Domain and does not require that N'Domain is the first text:

```
SELECT
  ds.SoftwareName,
  ds.CollectionName,
  crq.QueryExpression
  STUFF(crq.QueryExpression, 1, charindex('N''Domain\', 
    REPLICATE('w', LEN('N''Domain\')-1) + crq.QueryExpression), '')
FROM
  v_DeploymentSummary ds
JOIN 
  v_CollectionRuleQuery crq
ON ds.CollectionID = crq.CollectionID
```

Example:

```
SELECT 
  STUFF(x, 1, charindex('N''Domain\', 
    replicate('w', LEN('N''Domain\')-1) + x), '')
FROM (values('N''Domain\xxx'),('N''Doma'),('xxN''Domain\yyy')) x(x)
```

Result:

```
xxx
N'Doma
yyy
```